# Retrofit+Okhttp.HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I used the POST request to access the server and DO NOT send data to the server while GET data from the server.

`@POST("Index/getListShopsInfo")
 Observable<ShopList> getListShopsInfo();`

and I want to add a local cache for my data.

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context mContext;

    public CacheInterceptor(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        boolean netAvailable = AppUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext);
        if (netAvailable) {
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                .build();
        } else {
        request = request.newBuilder()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
            .build();
        }
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (netAvailable) {
            response = response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60 * 60)
                .build();
        } else {
            response = response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                .build();
        }
        return response;
    }
}


File cacheFile = new File(AppUtils.getDiskCacheDir(getContext()), "responses");
Cache cache = new Cache(cacheFile, App.DEFAULT_DIR_CACHE);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor(getContext()))
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .cache(cache)
    .build();`

mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(App.LOGINURL)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

When the network is connected,I can access the server,but when the network is not connected,my post will be intercept. And it will log the wrong:

> HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)

I have checked the local cache path and it does have the "responses" folder that I built,and there is a file named "journal" in it.When I open it in text format,it is like this:

[image]

And I don't know how to solve it.

Hope anyone could help me!

Comment: By the way,I changed POST request to GET.It is NULL of response body and still "Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)" of response message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I search it for several day and I found the solution.

FIRST.change the POST request to the GET.

`@GET("Index/getListShopsInfo")
 Call<ShopList> getListShopsInfo();`

SECOND.Change the Inteceptor.

```
private final Interceptor REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        String cacheControl = originalResponse.header("Cache-Control");
        if (cacheControl == null || cacheControl.contains("no-store") || cacheControl.contains("no-cache") ||
                cacheControl.contains("must-revalidate") || cacheControl.contains("max-age=0")) {
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 5000)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return originalResponse;
        }
    }
};

private final Interceptor REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR_OFFLINE = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (!AppUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached")
                    .build();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
};
```

THIRD.the okhttpClient.

```
File cacheFile = new File(AppUtils.getDiskCacheDir(getContext()), "FuckYouSecondDad");
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheFile, App.DEFAULT_DIR_CACHE);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .cache(cache)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR)
            .addInterceptor(REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR_OFFLINE)
            .build();
```

FORTH.the retrofit.

```
mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(App.LOGINURL)
            .client(mClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Now when the internet is connected,I got the cache.It is like this:

[image]

And the most important of all,do not forget to add this:

```
.removeHeader("Pragma")
```

or you will get the wrong of 504 again.

Comment: I have followed the exact same solution but it's still giving me 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cache) error. What do you I do?

Comment: Check your file manager in test machine,do you have the cache like the picture I uploaded？

Comment: I understand that the 504 means that the interceptor need to use your cache in local file but it did not find any cache.So check if you have build the folder or have the cache.

Comment: I'm also getting 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)

Comment: @Makalele  I solved it by changing `pragma` variable  `no-cache` to `cache`

Comment: @TejasPandya, How did you solve it ? Can you please share your answer ?